# Pinterest button - cancelling doesnt return to my page

Tags: html, pinterest

I have a bit of a problem here.

When I use the "Pin it" button on my site, and hit cancel, I wind up on a blank grey screen rather than being returned to my site.

Ideally, if a user cancelled pinning an image, they would return to my page.

I dont know why this is happening.  I have looked on pinterest for documentation and found nothing relating to this.  The pinterest button is basically a simple copy and paste (plus a javascript call before the end of the body tag...

Any advice on a solution?

thanks

Comment: Uch - I realized that I removed the script at the bottom of the body tag with a keyboard ctrl-undo.  Once replaced, it worked fine

Comment: Leaving this question/answer here for future solution seekers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pinterest script was not at the bottom of the page.  That was the issue.  Closing